# Batch file to copy last line of several files into one new file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a load of logs being generated each time an app runs, I want the very last line of each to be collated into a file or printed on screen by a batch file. e.g I have a dir with files like log123.log,log124.log,log125.log

Comment: You're talking Windows, right?

Comment: pity! it would be so much easier in a \*nix OS.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true, if I was familiar with Powershell I imagine it would be less horrible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can indeed be done with a Windows batch file, using a `for` loop to count the lines:

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*.log) do (
    set /a line_count = -1
    for /f %%l in (%%f) do set /a line_count += 1
    more +%line_count% %%f
)
```

If your files do not end with a newline character, you'll have to initialize the `line_count` variable to `0` instead of `-1`.

You can redirect `more`'s output to append the results to a file:

```
more +%line_count% %%f >> your_results_file
```